# PHP module crashes on ts_allocate_dtor

Tags: php, module, gdb

I am running PHP 5.4.0 on Linux.

Here is the code in ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION

```
#ifdef ZTS
ts_allocate_id( &sample_globals_id,
    sizeof(zend_sample_globals),
    (ts_allocate_ctor) php_sample_init_globals,
    (ts_allocate_dtor) php_sample_destroy_globals);
#else
    php_sample_init_globals(& sample_globals TSRMLS_CC);
#endif
```

This code crashes, when module finishes its MSHUTDOWN. GDB points to TSRM.c , this line (the call to dtor):

```
if (p->storage[j]) {
    if (resource_types_table && !resource_types_table[j].done && resource_types_table[j].dtor) {
    resource_types_table[j].dtor(p->storage[j], &p->storage);
    }
free(p->storage[j]);
}
```

Even stranger, when I replace the destructor function with NULL, it works. Like this:

```
ts_allocate_id( &sample_globals_id,
    sizeof(zend_sample_globals),
    (ts_allocate_ctor) php_sample_init_globals,
    NULL ); //Works, but destructor is not called
```

Perhaps anybody has an idea why this could happen?
Thank you

Comment: What form of crash?  Could this be a double free?

Comment: I don't think so, it crashes even when the destructor php_sample_destroy_globals() is empty.
The crash is segmentation fault

Comment: Actually, it looks very similar to this case
http://osdir.com/ml/php.pecl.devel/2007-03/msg00036.html

Answer (score 2):

Found it.
Strangely, this is not described in ANY tutorial, but the answer lies in source codes in ext directories.

I've added the next code to MSHUTDOWN

```
#ifdef ZTS
    ts_free_id(sample_globals_id); 
#endif
```

And now it works fine. Phhew...